# gecko cookie delete and gecko proxy

Tags: vb.net, gecko

i am using gecko browser to navigate to a site and the site leaves a cookie that i want to delete after im done with it. how do i delete cookies from my gecko browser?

oh and does anyone know how to implement a proxy system into my browser the one way i know is

```
status.Items.Add("Setting Proxy")
        Skybound.Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User("network.proxy.type") = 1
        Skybound.Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User("network.proxy.http") = TextBox2.Text
        Skybound.Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User("network.proxy.http_port") =
```

but with that way i cannot grab info from a textbox when setting the proxy port

Answer (score 0):

For deleting entire cookie :

```
nsICookieManager CookieMan;
            CookieMan = Xpcom.GetService<nsICookieManager>("@mozilla.org/cookiemanager;1");
            CookieMan = Xpcom.QueryInterface<nsICookieManager>(CookieMan);
            CookieMan.RemoveAll();
```

And for assigning `port` , you have to provide the integer value not a string.

```
Skybound.Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User("network.proxy.type") = 1;
Skybound.Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User("network.proxy.http") = TextBox2.Text;
Skybound.Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User("network.proxy.http_port") = 8080;
```

If you are getting proxy value from `textbox` , Split that using ':' and assign as follows

```
Skybound.Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User("network.proxy.type") = 1;
Skybound.Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User("network.proxy.http") = TextBox2.Text.Split(':')[0];
Skybound.Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User("network.proxy.http_port") = int.Parse(TextBox2.Text.Split(':')[1]);
```